# PHP not displaying result from MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code

```
$sql = "SET @uid := (SELECT ID FROM channels WHERE Used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);";
$sql = "UPDATE channels SET Used = 1 WHERE ID = @uid;";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM channels WHERE ID IN = @uid;";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)
                 or die( mysqli_error($sql) );
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $text = '';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
      $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
      $text =  $text . $Channel_Location;

    }       
}
```

Now the issue i'm having is the php isnt displaying the result returned by the MYSQL query which is stored in a session later on in the code to be displayed on a dummy page it comes up with the following error

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

The my SQL query does exactly what I need it to I just need to, so I don't really want to change it.  I just need some advice on how i'd get the PHP to echo the @uid 
is there anyone willing to help me solve the issue? if so thankyou.

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php you have 3 queries in your `$sql` so you should use `multi_query` function

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- you have errors, which is why that line is reached with a non mysqli_result parameter.

Comment: So edited the code to  `$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);` and still no luck

Comment: Your first query generates a result set, not a single ID, which you store in **@uid**. Then your second query (UPDATE) uses this value as if it were a single ID, but this is not true. I believe you should change **ID = @uid** to **ID IN @uid" and this could solve your problem.

Comment: Tried that @EddeAlmeida and apparently just throws an error

Comment: Tried that with multi_query?

Comment: I've updated my current code to reflect the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 queries in your $sql so you should use multi_query function
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

And you can change your first query to:

```
SET @uid = 0;
SELECT @uid := ID FROM channels WHERE Used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

**Update** You can try this fragment of your code modified with all commented improvements.

```
$sql = 'SET @uid = 0;';
$sql .= 'SELECT @uid:= ID FROM channels WHERE Used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);';
$sql .= 'UPDATE channels SET Used = 1 WHERE ID = @uid;';
$sql .= 'SELECT * FROM channels WHERE ID IN = @uid;';
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
   do {
       $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
   } while(mysqli_next_result($conn));
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $text = '';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
       $Channel_Location = $row['Channel_Location'];
       $text =  $text . $Channel_Location;
     }       
   }
} else {
  die( mysqli_error($conn) );
}
```

Comment: Can i be cheeky im rather new to this could you update my code to explain what you mean?

Comment: Your changes have introduced a new problem. You're replacing the sql each time instead of adding to it. (The second and third `$sql =` need to be `$sql .=`.)

Comment: Hey alex sorry about the late reply, i've tested this code but comes up with 2 errors saying the `$result` is an undefined variable in `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {` and  `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,`

Comment: are you sure you copied my code? the issue could be if you changed this part `while(mysqli_next_result($conn))  $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);` I mean there is no `{` after `while...` condition. Are you sure you did not add that brace?

Comment: Yeah literally copied it straight over? and never changed a thing  and I've just copied it over again and still no luck with it  still displays the same errors

Comment: you can try to comment all lines `$sql.=...` so leave just first query in query string and check if it executes. I guess we have some broken query inside multiquery string, but we have to find which one.

Comment: Ive fixed the first error, it was a ) at the end of the second sql query but cant solve the second `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`

Comment: you mean `UPDATE` stucks?

Comment: Solved the second error it was an error in my query i had `IN = @uid` where it should of just been `= @uid` on the final query, now it returns a new error `Strict standards: mysqli_next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method in `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112066/discussion-between-martin-beardmore-and-alex).